# Нужен совет по умному дому

Tags: raspberry-pi, esp8266, mqtt, iot, умный-дом

Коллега хочет реализовать у себя умный дом. Знаний и опыта в этой теме у него нет вообще.
Помогите определиться с хорошим подарком на НГ в пределах 1,5-2 тыс. рублей.
Сам думаю или книгу, или модуль/хаб, но подарить хаб - умышленно привязать к какой-либо экосистеме.

*P.S. Я знаю, что подобного рода вопросы не спрашивают на SO, но только здесь я могу рассчитывать на мнение опытных людей. Всё лучше, чем ответы@mail.ru*.

Comment: Ну интересно же - можно было бы и не закрывать пока)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком бюджете рекомендую книгу:

"Raspberry Pi. Сборник рецептов". Саймон Монк. О'Reilly 2017 год. Это второе издание. Я слышал, что вышло уже третье.

Книжка отличная - начиная с нулевого уровня. Разбирается на конкретных примерах куча вопросов. Есть глава и про умный дом. Каждая глава (проблема) состоит из 4 частей:

1. Постановка задачи
2. Предлагаемое решение
3. Обсуждение
4. Дополнительные сведения

С перечислением "железа" и исходами программ.

Comment: Спасибо. Обязательно посмотрю этот вариант.

Answer (score 3):

Ну вообще всё начинается с проекта, так на коленке тяп ляп не пояснишь.

1. Первое в чём стоит точно разобраться что от этого умного дома нужно.
2. Основные методы управления, будет там просто пультик ДУ который будет включать выключать свет. Или всё-же что посложнее.
3. Если что посложнее, то стоит начать с теории по пользованию тем-же MajorDoMo https://mjdm.ru/

Интересные каналы так или иначе посвящённые тематике умного дома своими руками.

- [https://www.youtube.com/c/КитайГ](https://www.youtube.com/c/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%93)
- [https://www.youtube.com/c/Электроникавобъективе](https://www.youtube.com/c/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5)

Советую начать с них, первый более развлекательный, а второй там реально технический с кучей готовых решений.

ps: Если хочется всё простенько, то можно тот-же Basic комплект от Xiaomi купить https://mi-shop.com/ru/catalog/smart_devices/novosel-basic-bundle/

Comment: Однако бюджет сильно ограничен. Возможно есть какие-то книги на примете, в которых описаны научно-популярным языком основы и разобраны пару технологий и экосистем?

Comment: Я умный дом начинал с Ардуино. По работе на Ардуино делал проект, потом начал изучать цифровую радиоинженерку. Аналоговую я по отцовским книгам учил, он был радиоинженером. Потом изучал ESP32 от туда уже полное общение с релюшками, датчиками и прочей фигнёй.